# C++ What's faster? static member function or ordinary one?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to studdy some performace things...
this question may sound stupid, but I'll give it a try.
Let's assume each function has 100 lines of same code.
or does this difference dosn't realy metter?
which one will be faster on execution in `main` function:

```
struct A
{
    static void f()
         {
               cout << "static one";
         }
};
```

or this one:

```
void f()
{
   cout << "non static";
}

int main()
{
      A::f();
      f();
}
```

Comment: Perhaps the ordinary one is faster because a static member function needs the class to be loaded (only one time) before being executable.

Comment: @Mr.TAMER: "Loading a class" has no meaning in C++.

Comment: @AlfP.Steinbach: personally, what makes me perplexe is that people ask those performance questions rather than trying to understand what's going on under the hood (and how syntax is transformed into executable code). If they took the time to research how such constructs are actually executed, then they would understand how meaningless their questions are.

Comment: @Alf: perhaps my comments on Als answer will throw a little light on why I bothered to answer....

Comment: @Als: I agree. I think it's possible and far more constructive to explain to people in what way their question is "silly", as part of an answer. A good answer doesn't need to use words like "silly" at all.

Comment: @SteveJessop: No worries.I will delete my reply to your comment as well.

Comment: @SteveJessop Now you're just being silly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no difference, the compiler works out the address at compile time and dispatches execution to it in one step at run-time (if it doesn't inline it, which it's equally able/likely to do with either).

Comment: thanks, I'm not afraid to say that I didn't know that, and your answer helps me alot so I can continue to write my libray while learning C++ in same time. cheers! vote+